# How to copy data from Cassandra to Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-spark, cassandra

How can I copy data from Cassandra to Elasticsearch? Should I use Spark, is there some convenient plugin/other tool to do it?

Cassandra version is 2.1.5 dsc

Spark version is 1.2.1

Elasticsearch version is 2.2.0

**EDIT**:

Im trying to achieve that with spark:

```
import org.elasticsearch.spark._
import org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.EsSpark

json_rdd = ...
EsSpark.saveToEs(json_rdd, "index_name")
```

Im trying to follow the https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/2.2/spark.html documntation but I cant find where is the connection to elasticsearch happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Install Spark in stand-alone mode, co-locate Spark workers on Cassandra nodes

2) Use the Spark-Cassandra connector to fetch data locally out of Cassandra

3) Use the Spark-ES connector to push data to ES

Comment: Can i connect the Cassandra 1.2.9 with Spark and transfer data to latest Elastic search ?